# Rails: Sass debugging behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, sass

I have an `application.css.scss` file where I declare requirement for all of the vendor imports, as well as the `main.scss` file, which, in turn, serves as a centralised import for all of my styles. So it goes like this: `application.css.scss < *=require main.scss < @import 'base/*'`
And as long as the problem occurs on the first two levels everything works as expected: I get Rails error page with the backtrace of a problem which is very neat and helpful. But since I'm using first two levels merely to declare requirements\imports, problems tend to occur on the third level, in the partials of the actual Sass.

And in this case Rails processes an error and proceeds to render me a `We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)` page, instead of a page with the backtrace. I still can debug using the terminal output, but it's very uncomfortable. Here's the logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 21:45:48 +0300
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
  Rendered application/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4073ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined mixin 'some-mixin'.
  (in /home/nh/test/app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss:5)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>test</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/assets/stylesheets/base/_typography.scss:5:in `some-mixin'
  app/assets/stylesheets/base/_typography.scss:5
  app/assets/stylesheets/base:1
  app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss:3
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__133417964296302123_38393380'
```

The question is how can I make Rails monitor errors and show backtrace page when operating a deeper levels of Sass imports?